# I need a guide on how to understand python

Tags: python, arrays, function, directory

[python] #ehmm... hello!! is anyone there? if there is; I really need help with python. I'm a core novice in need of help, anything at all just help me.
I wanted making the question precise, but I've been obliged to critically describe the problem.
so here's the story; I started trying to learn python in 2018, I dropped it after two days. then I started again march this  year, and till now, I still struggle.

Comment: I advise you to look for university lectures on python, obv online. I'm sure you can find them, I've found powerpoint presentations even on complex subjects such as quantum internet published by universities. Stay away from 'super easy tutorial sites' that have the solution to all problems: often the solutions you find are outdated (e.g. python2 instead of python3) or quick but dirty.

Answer (score 0):

Well, here is a series of lessons that really help me get of the ground. To be fair, I already had some experience with coding before picking up python.

https://www.kevinsheppard.com/teaching/python/course/